# Batch Script Looping Variables

Tags: windows, variables, batch-file

This is something simple I'm missing I bet and I have a feeling it's not working the way I need because of the nested loop. This is a simple script I've pulled off somewhere and have modified a bit to allow for more testing. Essentially it just pings a host on a delay over and over for all time until you close it, but logs the failed responses. Everything works, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to get it to update the name being used in the for loop.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:: ** Enter name to identify host in log **
set name1=Test 1
set name2=Test 2
set name3=Test 3

:: ** Enter IP or HOSTNAME to test against **
set hostIP1=1.1.1.1
set hostIP2=2.2.2.2
set hostIP3=3.3.3.3

:: ** Enter Delay in milliseconds between each test **
set delayMS=2000


title -DO NOT CLOSE- Ping Test
echo DO NOT CLOSE
echo Ping Test


:loop
set namecount=1
for %%x in (%hostIP1% %hostIP2% %hostIP3%) do (
set pingline=1
set pingname=name!namecount!
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('ping -n 1 -w 2000 -l 255 %%x') do (
    if !pingline! equ 2 (
        set logline=!date! !time! "%%A" - %%x !%pingname%!
        echo !logline! | find "TTL=">nul || echo !logline! >> pinglog.txt
        )
    set /a pingline+=1
    )
set /a namecount+=1
)
sleep -m %delayMS%
goto loop
```

Usually I'd use another language but I need something that works on windows servers of all kinds.. This seems like the surest way. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is incorrect:

```
!%pingname%!
```

Try this:

```
!Pingname!
```

I can't try your code but i've made other minor corrections:

(UPDATED)

```
 @echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:: ** Enter name to identify host in log **
set "name1=Test 1"
set "name2=Test 2"
set "name3=Test 3"

:: ** Enter IP or HOSTNAME to test against **
set "hostIP1=1.1.1.1"
set "hostIP2=2.2.2.2"
set "hostIP3=3.3.3.3"

:: ** Enter Delay in milliseconds between each test **
set /A "delayMS=2000"


title -DO NOT CLOSE- Ping Test
Echo DO NOT CLOSE
Echo Ping Test

:loop
set /A "namecount=1"
for %%x in (%hostIP1% %hostIP2% %hostIP3%) do (
    set /A "pingline=1"
    call set "pingname=%%name!namecount!%%"
    for /f "delims=" %%A in ('ping -n 1 -w 2000 -l 255 %%x') do (
        if !pingline! equ 2 (
            set "logline=%date% !time! %%A - %%x !pingname!"
            (echo !logline! | find "TTL=">nul) || (echo !logline! >> "pinglog.txt")
        )
        set /a "pingline+=1"
    )
    set /a "namecount+=1"
)
sleep -m %delayMS%
goto :loop
```

Comment: Thanks for the clean up. Unfortunately !pingname! doesn't work as it just comes up with the variable name I need expanded. So I do see name1 name2 name3 in the logs. With !%pingname%! I get the variable expanded but it stays at the same one, it doesn't increment properly.

Comment: that's because you are not getting the variable expanded, you are getting the var "%var%" all the time, adding !! with %% don't take ANY effect, i corrected one more thing in the code, i've updated my answer, you was setting bad the var at the line:     set "pingname=name!namecount!"

Comment: Gave it a shot but it's still only using name1 for all.

Comment: i've edited my answer, try the new code again, i've tried this time and it updates the names, but i don't know if updates the "X" times that you want, 1 update per round. (sorry for my english)

Comment: Fantastic. I see what I was missing with the `%%name!namecount!%%` part. This works exactly as expected now. Thanks a lot!